# paypal_lib form not working in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, paypal, codeigniter-3

I have loaded the paypal library in my controller and written the code as well for paypal integration.

```
class Register extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('paypal_lib');
     }
     public function signup()
     {
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('return', $returnURL);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('rm','2'); 
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('cancel_return', $cancelURL);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('notify_url', $notifyURL);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_number', $pkgid);

        $this->paypal_lib->paypal_auto_form();

     }
 }
```

On my template file:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : '<?php echo $base_url; ?>register/signup',
    type: 'POST',
    data: jQuery(form).serialize(),
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

I could not move to paypal website store. still on same page without any redirection. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i analyzed the issue. we shouldn't use paypal_lib on ajax. because of codeigniter ignoring the redirect concept on ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You don't return anything. Change your function "**signup**" to this:

```
class Register extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('paypal_lib');
     }
     public function signup()
     {
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('return', $returnURL);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('rm','2'); 
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('cancel_return', $cancelURL);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('notify_url', $notifyURL);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_number', $pkgid);
        echo json_encode($this->paypal_lib->paypal_auto_form(), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
     }
 }
```

And better in your JS code change your dataType to JSON:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/register/signup',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: jQuery(form).serialize(),
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did my answer solve the problem or was the problem elsewhere?
If I solved the problem please mark my answer as correct or write how you solved the problem.